# The proper way to use Firebase in Node.js/Express.js project

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to use Firebase in my Express.js project, I've already use Firebase in simple HTML/JS projects via script import, but I'm stuck with Express.js.

In short, I know the element required for running Firebase but not where to place it. First, here is the structure of my project

[image: project directory tree]

the logical way for me to use firebase was to put all the require and config in app.js but, this way, the fb var and the firebase object are not defined in index.pug

```
var firebase = require("firebase");
require('firebase/auth');
require('firebase/database');
require('firebase/storage');
var config = {
  apiKey: "X",
  authDomain: "X",
  databaseURL: "X",
  storageBucket: "X",
  messagingSenderId: "X"
};
var fb = firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

i tryied multiple solution like `module.exports.fb = fb.database();` but again, i don't know where to put `import fb from '/node_modules'` in order to get things working

side note: the aim of my project is to GET the twitch api, put some data in Database and display it in HTML webpage, my need is to be able to access firebase globally in my pug files or js files

Comment: You can't pass the Firebase app through to Pug, as there's no connection between the two once the compiled HTML is sent. If you want direct access to Firebase on both the client and the server, you'll need to initialize it both on the server and the client. Alternatively, use Firebase entirely from the backend, and expose an API to the frontend.

Comment: i just don't want to expose my firebase app token to everyone, also what is for you the right way to make an API ?

Comment: In that case your only option is to create an API to interact with Firebase. To do that, just set up routes with Express that do the desired operations in Firebase and make requests from the frontend. Also note that Firebase supports security rules to limit access, and with a proper frontend set up, it's safe to expose the API key.

Comment: the way for safe expose is by using auth in firebase right ?

Comment: Correct. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/.